# Does Tywin Lannister ever address Varys as "Lord"?

Tags: game-of-thrones, a-song-of-ice-and-fire

In season 4 episode 6, Oberyn addresses Varys as "Lord Varys." Varys notes that no one is under any obligation to call him "lord," but Oberyn shrewdly notes that everyone calls him that anyway. Does Tywin Lannister ever address Varys as such, on the show or in the books?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Does Tywin Lannister ever address Varys as such, on the show or in the
>   books?

Lord Tywin *references* him as such in *A Storm of Swords*, Chapter 72, but as Varys is not in the room at the time that may not meet your definition of *addressing him*.

> "Heal him," Lord Tywin said again, vexed. "You are aware that Lord
>   Varys has sent fishermen into the waters around Dragonstone. They
>   report that..."

As Lord Tywin

> died

soon thereafter, we may never know if he addressed Varys by that title to his face.

Comment: Nice quote. I looked up the context: Tywin is trying to persuade a reluctant Pycelle to heal Gregor, arguing that good relations with Dorne must be prioritised while Stannis remains a threat. As ever with Tywin there's a reason: the "Lord" here appears to be chosen to give Varys's information more clout.